# Using explain( "executionStats" ) to Find Number of Shards Queried?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use `.explain( "executionStats" )` to find how many shards are queried in a find query and how many documents are examined. The second one is easy, find `"totalDocsExamined" :` and your done, but I don't know what to look for to find out how many shards are queried.

What should I be looking for to identify how many total shards are queried?

Modified input:

`db.collection.find( { ... } ).limit( 5 ).explain( "executionStats" )`

Output:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "collection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "field1" : {
                                                "$eq" : "T"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "field2" : {
                                                "$eq" : "A"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "limitAmount" : 5,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "field1" : 1,
                                                "field2" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "indexName",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "field1" : [ ],
                                                "field2" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "field1" : [
                                                        "[\"T\", \"T\"]"
                                                ],
                                                "field2" : [
                                                        "[\"A\", \"A\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 5,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 15,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 5,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 5,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "nReturned" : 5,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 6,
                        "advanced" : 5,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "limitAmount" : 5,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "nReturned" : 5,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 5,
                                "advanced" : 5,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 0,
                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "docsExamined" : 5,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "nReturned" : 5,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                        "works" : 5,
                                        "advanced" : 5,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 0,
                                        "restoreState" : 0,
                                        "isEOF" : 0,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "field1" : 1,
                                                "field2" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "indexName",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "field1" : [ ],
                                                "field2" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "field1" : [
                                                        "[\"T\", \"T\"]"
                                                ],
                                                "field2" : [
                                                        "[\"A\", \"A\"]"
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "keysExamined" : 5,
                                        "seeks" : 1,
                                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "MSI",
                "port" : 27501,
                "version" : "3.6.2",
                "gitVersion" : "578d186dbd0f0320a7ca04d39fd78d0a2c659350"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Additional Requested Info:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > version()
3.6.2

MongoDB Enterprise > db.collection.getShardDistribution()
Collection collection is not sharded.
```

Comment: Are you querying against a sharded collection (and through a `mongos`)? If so, the explain output should include `shards` information in the `winningPlan` and `execution` stages. See: [Explain Results: Sharded Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#sharded-collection) in the MongoDB documentation. If this is definitely a sharded collection queried through `mongos`, can you confirm the output of `version()` and `db.collection.getShardDistribution()`?

Comment: Hmm.. Even though I created shards s1 and s2, and started them they don't seem to be in use according to `db.collection.getShardDistribution()`. I'll check over setup instructions.

Comment: Databases and collections are not sharded automatically: a sharded deployment can contain both unsharded and sharded data. You need to run `sh.enableSharding()` for a database and then [specify a shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) using `sh.shardCollection()` . See the [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) tutorial in the MongoDB manual for specific steps.